# How to check the error code after a console program exits

Tags: windows-7, command-line

After a program exits from command line, how can I check the exit code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ERRORLEVEL` will contain the exit code of the last command. Example:

```
C:\> echo %ERRORLEVEL%
0

C:\> cmd /c exit 1

C:\> echo %ERRORLEVEL%
1

C:\> IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO An error occurred!
An error occurred!
```

Note that in the example above, the `IF` statement will succeed when `ERRORLEVEL` is 1 *or more*.

Comment: You can also check for other relationships ("exactly equal", for example): `IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 ECHO Error`

Comment: `sh`-style `something || iffailed` and `something && ifsuccess` are possible too.